# How to search a value in a list between given positions

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list with three values (strings) and a substring.

1. Each string in the list needs to be searched for the given substring between position 20 and 50 and printed out if there's more than 5 occurances (of this substring in each string).
2. If the string lacks the substring a message should be printed that the substring is missing (in each list item).

The output should be (considering my code below)

```
1 Enriched with SP1 binding sites
3 Contains no SP1 binding sites
```

```
seq_list = ["GGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGG", "GGGCGG", "BBBBBBB"]
binding_site = "GGGCGG"


for count, value in enumerate(seq_list, start=1):               
    if binding_site in value:
        sumSP = int(sum(s.count('GGCGG')for s in seq_list))
        if sumSP >20:
            print(count, "enriched with SP1 binding sites")

else:
    print(count,"No binding sites found.")
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkEXx.png)

So I've got two problems. First, I've scoured the internet for a simple solution to search each string between pos 20-50 but only manage to find how to search the entire lists positions (using slice).
The second problem is that my code `sumSP` doesn't work since it gives true for my second string which should be false, since it's only value 1 in my list that holds more than 5 binding_sites.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: do you know about the KMP algorithm?

Comment: Overlapping occurrences or not?

Comment: KMP algorithm feels a bit overcourse at the moment, just taking a short basic course in Python :)
There shouldn't be any overlapping occurrances.

Comment: @qwr I don't see how that would help.

Comment: @KellyBundy substring matching is exactly what KMP does

Comment: @qwr But how is that better than using the `str` methods?

Comment: I thought it was a homework problem to implement the algorithm. Otherwise yes you can use builtins.

Comment: Yup, homework it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code closely follows your code snippet. It uses two calls to `str.find()` to find the binding site at all and between positions 20 and 50.

```py
seq_list = ["GGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGG", "GGGCGG", "BBBBBBB"]
binding_site = "GGGCGG"

for count, value in enumerate(seq_list, start=1):
    if value.find(binding_site) != -1:
        if value.find(binding_site, 20, 50) != -1:
            sumSP = value.count('GGCGG')
            if sumSP >= 5:
                print(count, "enriched with SP1 binding sites")
        else:
            print(count,"No binding sites found.")
```

Output:

```
1 enriched with SP1 binding sites
2 No binding sites found.
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is what I think you want but can be easily modified. It uses REGEX as a simple way to count sub-string occurences. It shows how to search a portion of a string.

```
import re

seq_list = ["GGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGGAAAAGGGCGG", "GGGCGG", "BBBBBBB"]
binding_site = "GGGCGG"
search_for = 'GGCGG'
START = 20
FINISH = 50

for i, seq  in enumerate(seq_list):
    if not binding_site in seq:
        print(f"seq {i} No binding sites found.")
    elif len(seq) < FINISH:
        print(f"seq {i} length {len(seq)} less than search size {FINISH}")
    else:
        num = len(re.findall(search_for, seq[START:FINISH]))
        print(f"seq {i} has {num} found - enriched with SP1 binding sites")
```

which gives:

```
seq 0 has 3 found - enriched with SP1 binding sites
seq 1 length 6 less than search size 50
seq 2, No binding sites found.
```

Note that because Python is zero-indexed, START 20 is index position 20 and so the 21st character and so on, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: What's the advantage over `seq[START:FINISH].count(search_for)`?

Comment: Thank you! I'm not allowed to use any add-ons for this specific exercise but I'll save this for future reference :)

Comment: @SaraStensson What's an "add-on"?

Comment: Or even `seq.count(search_for, START, FINISH)`...

Comment: Sorry - didn't know re was a built-in module :)

Comment: I used regex to show a flexible approach which can easily be modified to search for options (**this** or **that**), search for a substring only occurring in the midst of another specified substring, search for variations of a pattern and so on as might well be useful for genetic sequences. For this specific question `.count` works just as well.

Comment: Thank you! The solution is great, but I didn't need to write out that much data for this task. I'll save it though for future reference :)